# Why the Time Complexity of my python code O(N**2)

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I am having a tough time understanding how time complexity is calculated for a python code. Why is the time complexity of the below code O(N**2) ?

```
from itertools import permutations

indices = list(permutations(range(len(A)),2))
indices = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[1], indices))
Y = [(A[i], A[j]) for i,j in indices]

count = sum(x>y for x,y in Y)

if count >= 1000000000:
    count = -1
return count
```

Comment: Your code isn't `O(n)` as posted, because it doesn't work at all. Also note that consuming iterators you don't need all the values of into a list completely defeats the point of `itertools`.

Comment: Hi jonrsharpe, The code works and gives the desired output. But it isnt good enough from performance perspective, apparently. I used itertools because I wanted all permutations of length 2 from a list of size N. Please suggest an alternative way of doing this without itertools. Also, why is this above code O(N**2), I do not undertstand the fundamental issue here.

Comment: No it doesn't; as you've posted it there is a syntax error and a name error. But if performance is a problem, look into not keeping creating pointless lists from iterators. Keeping using `itertools`, but do it correctly!

Comment: Hi user3483203, Thanks!. as I asked jonrsharpe, - "I used itertools because I wanted all permutations of length 2 from a list of size N. Please suggest an alternative way of doing this without itertools."

Comment: @RajeshKumar It's not permutations which is the problem, it is that you then create a list from this iterator.

Comment: Hi Jonrsharpe, Agree that I may not be using itertools appropriately. Can you suggest a way I can - "get all permutations of length 2 from a list of size N". for example, if my list is [1,2,3], I want to get the output - [(1,2), (1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)].

Comment: @user3483203.  `permutations` will generate `n*(n-1)` tuples in this case - which is O(n**2)

Comment: @RajeshKumar.  NO!  You do *not* want `[(1,2), (1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2)]` what you want is something that will generate those on demand.

Comment: @MartinBonner I think you're right, it would be `n!` permutations only if it's generating `len(n)` permutations of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list (or other indexable object A), and are trying to count how many pairs `A[i]`, `A[j]` (where i < j) have `A[i] > A[j]`.

Your current implementation needs to consider *all* pairs `i`, `j`, and there are O(`len(A)**2`) of them.  (Therefore you have O(n`**`2) comparisons.)

You might be able to do much better by creating tuples `(A[i], i)` and sorting them (on `A[i]`).  Then some clever counting algorithm on when the indices are out of order (and by how much) will probably give you the result.  The sort will be O(n ln n), and the scan over the indices might even be linear.

Sorting would look like:

```
import operator
sortedA = sorted( enumerate(A), operator.itemgetter(1) ) // Sort by A[i]
```

The scan would look something like:

```
count = 0
for x in sortedA:
    finalPosition = x[0]
    originalPosition = x[1][0]
    // I am almost certain the next two lines are wrong - but something
    // similar ought to do the job
    if finalPosition < originalPosition:  
        count += originalPosition - finalPosition
```

---

You can speed your current code by not creating lists.

```
indices = permutations(range(len(A)),2)
indices = filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[1], indices)
count = sum(A[i] > A[j] for i,j in indices)
```

(But that is not as good as O(n`**`2) to O(n log n)

Comment: Hi Matin, Thanks a lot. I tried an alternative, but still it is apparently of time complexity O(N**2):      

count = 0
    
    data = list(zip(list(range(len(A))), A))
    for p,q in data:
        filt_data = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] > p and x[1] < q, data))
        count = count + len(filt_data)
    
    if count >= 1000000000:
        count = -1
    return count

Comment: is it the filer inside the loop ??

Comment: @RajeshKumar have you read his answer properly? You need to *sort* the list in order to improve on O(N^2).

Comment: @RajeshKumar **WHY** do you keep spraying these `list` constructors around your code?  That just forces a copy of the data.

Comment: Thanks Martin and @meowgoesthedog.  I tried sorting and also removed the unnecessary lists. But that isnt solving the issue of O(N**2). May be I havent got the approach yet. But nevertheless, your inputs were very helpful.